# Python - Creating permutations with output array index constraints

Tags: python, iteration, permutation, python-itertools

I want to create all possible permutations for an array in which each element can only occur once, with constraints on the element array index position.

ID = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"]

I want to create all possible permutations of the original_array, however the positions of each element are restricted to index positions given by:

```
ID = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"]

Index_Options=[]
for i in range(len(ID)):
    List1=[]
    distance=3
    value = i - distance
    for j in range((int(distance)*2)):
        if value < 0 or value > len(ID):
            print("Disregard") #Outside acceptable distance range
        else:
            List1.append(value)
        value=value+1
    Index_Options.append(List1)
    print(Index_Options)

#Index_Options gives the possible index positions for each element. ie "A" can occur in only index positions 0,1,2, "B" can occur in only index positions 0,1,2,3 ect.
```

I'm just struggling on how to then use this information to create all the output permutations.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function to build the combinations. Instead of generating all possible permutations from `ID` and then filtering based on `Index_Options`, it is much more efficient to produce a cartesian product of `ID` by directly traversing `Index_Options`:

```
ID = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"]
def combos(d, c = [], s = []):
  if not d:
     yield c
  else:
     for i in filter(lambda x:x not in s and x < len(ID), d[0]):
        yield from combos(d[1:], c=c+[ID[i]], s=s+[i])

print(list(combos(Index_Options)))
```

Output (first ten combinations produced):

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'I'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'H', 'J'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'J', 'H'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'J', 'H', 'I'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'J', 'I', 'H'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'G', 'I', 'J'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'G', 'J', 'I'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'G', 'J'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'G']]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, this worked great, and was more efficient that the permutations method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.permutations` to create all the possible permutations and then create new list with a check if all the letters are in the correct position

```
permutations = [p for p in itertools.permutations(ID, len(ID)) if all(i in Index_Options[ID.index(x)] for i, x in enumerate(p))]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked well and achieved the desired outcome :)